# Cognito Identity Service

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

To me need create user and get temporary credentials to use another service (cloudWatch)?
How get temporary credentials? If i use my credentials this is worked but this not secure.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.region = 'region';
var credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    AccountId: 'accountId',
    RoleArn: 'role',
    IdentityPoolId: 'pool',
});

AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'});
// AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'key', secretAccessKey: 'secretKey'});
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

get(){
var paramsCreateUser = {
      UserPoolId: 'pool',
      Username: 'name',
      UserAttributes: [{
        Name: 'email',
        Value: 'e@gmail.com'
      }]
    };

    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(paramsCreateUser, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else     console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set your AWS credentials in your Lambda. You should create an IAM role which the Lambda executes as, which has the permission your function needs. See [Loading Credentials for a Node.js Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-lambda.html).

> When you create an AWS Lambda function, you must create a special IAM
>   role that has permission to execute the function. This role is called
>   the execution role. When you set up a Lambda function, you must
>   specify the IAM role you created as the corresponding execution role.
>
> The execution role provides the Lambda function with the credentials
>   it needs to run and to invoke other web services. As a result, you do
>   not need to provide credentials to the Node.js code you write within a
>   Lambda function.

1. Go into IAM. Create a new role, lets call it 'lambda-create-cognito-user'
2. Assign the policy 'AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole' and 'AmazonCognitoPowerUser' to the role
3. Go into the Lambda console and set you function to be executed as 'lambda-create-cognito-user'

EDIT: If you need to access another service, just add the required policy to IAM role. For example you might add the policy 'CloudWatchFullAccess'.